# Xubuntu: computer can't be reached over ssh after being idle for a period of time

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, xubuntu

This started happening after installing Xubuntu 14.04 instead of an old Ubuntu, so I believe the wireless card is not to blame. After being idle for a small period of time (roughly 15-30 minutes) I will stop being able to connect to the computer over SSH ("Network is unreachable"). Computer doesn't loose WiFi and e.g. TeamViewer doesn't loose connection.

Oddly enough if I start pinging my router or some website from the Xubuntu computer, the SSH connection to it will go through the same instant, as if it just woke up. If leave a Terminal window with ping running, computer will be available for SSH connections for days.

I use openssh-server.

If I leave an existing SSH session idle, it disconnects after 15-30 mintues unless I leave a ping on on the server.